# Using run method of unittest.TestCase

Tags: python

Can someone point me to an example of using the `run()` method of `unittest.Testcase` in python ?

Comment: What do you want to do with it?

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa Just wanted to understand how to use it while writing tests.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you don't need to use `run()` method yourself when writing the tests. Your test classes inherit this from your test base classes.

When you run the tests you use a launcher like `python -m unittest` the unit test runner then internally takes care of calling `run()`. Unless you have some very specific reason you do not need to care or think `run()`.

Examples how to run unit tests:

```
python -m unittest test_module1 test_module2
python -m unittest test_module.TestClass
python -m unittest test_module.TestClass.test_method
```

https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/unittest.html#command-line-interface

Comment: Still how can I use `run()` if I wanted to ?

Comment: Look the source code of any unit test framework you are using and see how it calls run